# linux shell search for number that does not ocur between numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to search for a number in string that does not occur between numbers.

For example:
string="10003096,10007051,10003098,10007053,10000952,10002696,10003619,900004608"

If i search for 10003096, then it exists.
But if i search for 1000, then it means it does not exist.
Even if i search for 10000952,10002696, then it means it does not exist.

How can i write the shell script for this?

Please help.

I have tried various options with grep and sed but it does not help.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you try re-phrasing the entire question?

Comment: Are you trying to see if a number exists in the **range** specified by your `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad both your 'needle' and 'haystack' with commas.  E.g.

echo ",$string," | grep ",10007053,"

Comment: How does this match numbers in a range *between* other numbers? Or maybe nobody understands the question yet...

Comment: I used the only interpretation of the question that seemed to work...  I don't have great confidence that I've understood it to be honest!